# Possible to Recover Files from Remote Volume?

Tags: software-recommendation, data-recovery

Is there any software that will allow you to recover files from a remote volume? I have a NAS, and one of its volumes lost all its files. I can't just plug the NAS into a computer so I need to be able to do it over the network.

Comment: Can you tell us which NAS you are using? That would help us to answer your question more definitely.

Comment: LaCie Cloudbox.

Answer (score -1):

TestDisk is powerful free data recovery software! It was primarily designed to help recover lost partitions and/or make non-booting disks bootable again when these symptoms are caused by faulty software: certain types of viruses or human error (such as accidentally deleting a Partition Table). Partition table recovery using TestDisk is really easy.

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

Comment: It doesn't say it will recover files from a remote volume.